# Acceder a una propiedad de un objeto

Tags: java

Como acceder a la propiedad de un objeto o de un objeto relacionado, usando classmetadata o reflection?

Supongamos que tenemos estas clases

```
class Person {    
    public String name;

    public void Person( name ) {
       this.name = name;
    }

}

class A {
    public String name;
    public void A(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

class B {
    public Person person;
    public void A(name) {
        this.person = new Person(name)
    }
}
```

Como vemos, existen formas diferentes para acceder a la propiedad name

Para la primera clase:

```
A p = new A("Tom")
// Access to the name
p.name
```

Para la segunda clase

```
B p = new B("Tom")
// Access to the name
p.person.name
```

Ahora supongan que necesitamos desde una clase generica acceder a la propiedad nombre de las 2 clases, pero la clase generica no conoce de esta estructura.
Esta clase necesitaria de alguna manera acceder a la informacion de como es la estrucutra. Escuche algo asi como metadata o reflection.

Cual seria la manera correcta para obtener y usar esta informacion?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que no uses la aproximación que indicas. Lo mejor es que te crees una interfaz para obtener ese dato y la implementes con las clases que quieras que respondan a esa clase genérica:

```
public interface Nombrable {
    public String getNombre();
}
```

Y la implementas en tus clases:

```
public class A implements Nombrable {
    String name;
    @Override
    public String getNombre() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class B implements Nombrable {
    @Override
    public String getNombre() {
        return person.name;
    }
}
```

Así podrás acceder al nombre con el método `getNombre()` pues has definido que implementan esa interfaz.

```
String nombreA = a.getNombre();
String nombreB = b.getNombre();
```

Y además puedes especificar en tu genérico que sean de ese tipo si haces la declaración como `<T extends Nombrable>`

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses Reflexión ya que además te permitiría obtener valores de variables privadas. Te dejo el link para que le eches un vistado. 
[Link de Java Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html)

```
public class PrivateObject {

  private String privateString = null;

  public PrivateObject(String privateString) {
     this.privateString = privateString;
  }

}
```

Y esta es la parte de Reflexion:

```
PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject("The Private Value");
Field privateStringField = PrivateObject.class.getDeclaredField("privateString");

privateStringField.setAccessible(true); // Ponemos la variable publica

String fieldValue = (String) privateStringField.get(privateObject);
System.out.println("fieldValue = " + fieldValue);
```